# Why does it make sense to duplicate pointers in order to solve block-based retain-cycles under ARC?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

Under ARC, a block is suspected to cause a retain cycle if you're using `self` inside the block, for example.

I've seen a [workaround here](http://ios.biomsoft.com/2011/12/24/migrating-your-code-to-objective-c-arc/), like this:
[image]

How can this workaround prevent a retain cycle?

`weakRequest` is just a pointer to the exact same object referenced by `request`. When ARC modifies the retain count of `weakRequest` or `request`, it's affecting the same object.

Then, in the block, there is this strange thing going on:

```
__strong ASIHTTPRequest *strongRequest = weakRequest;
```

This is the eqivalent to saying:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *strongRequest = weakRequest;
[strongRequest retain];
```

But again: It's one and the same object. Why all these different variable names? They're just pointers!

I never really cared much about blocks and tried to avoid them. But now this made me curious about what everyone is talking about when they say "a block captures the variables". Until today I thought this just means a block will retain every pointer you use which has been defined outside of the scope of the block, meaning that the block just retains whatever object you touch in it's scope.

I did this quick test:

```
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
[self.view addSubview:v];
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

NSLog(@"self = %p", self); // 0x6a12a40

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{
                     UIViewController *my = self;
                     NSLog(@"my = %p", my); // 0x6a12a40
                     v.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100);
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

Like you can see the object itself stays exactly the same. The block does not create a copy. So I can safely assume all the years of C and Objective-C knowledge are still valid:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *strongRequest = internetRequest;
ASIHTTPRequest *foo = strongRequest;
ASIHTTPRequest *bar = foo;

if (bar == internetRequest) {
    NSLog(@"exact same thing, of course");
}
```

So what is going on there? How can this resolve a retain count if all that's happening is create different pointers to the same object? Why the extra mile of creating those pointers?

Wouldn't this be totally the same thing?

```
[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSString *respondeString = [request responseString];
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(pingSuccessful:)]) {
        [_delegate pingSuccessful:responseString];
    }
}];
```

There must be some secret about Objective-C which explains why duplicating pointers solves memory management problems here. It just doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It actually has nothing to do with ARC, but rather how blocks capture variables.  The pointer is duplicated so that the variable captured by the block has the correct ownership qualifier.

> *weakRequest is just a pointer to the exact same object referenced by request. When ARC modifies the retain count of weakRequest or request, it's affecting the same object.*

Right, they both point to the same object, but `weakRequest` has the `__unsafe_unretained` ownership qualifier, which means that when that variable is captured by the block, its retain count is unchanged.

If `request` were captured by the block then it would be retained and you would have retain cycle, regardless of whether you're using ARC.

The conversion back to a `__strong` pointer simply keeps that object alive for the duration that block execution.

Comment: I could be wrong here, but I don't think the __strong pointer inside the block keeps it alive for the duration of the block.  The only way ARC can do this is to retain the object, which would create a retain-cycle, especially since ARC can't know the lifespan of the block (most likely it is being stored for execution later).  If it does retain the block (and I don't think it does), then adding the __strong variable inside the block completely defeats the purpose of the __weak variable outside the block.

Comment: Great explanation! @Aaron, I think the problem with the retain cycle is that if you create a block and don't use it for a long time, the retained object might not go away until the block is executed and releases the object. In this case, now it makes sense to me: The request object is retained inside the block *when the block begins*, and after that, it is released and the retain cycle is broken. Of course this opens the possibility that the request object deallocates before the block executes, if the block executes with delay. Right?

Comment: Right, the main reason to use __weak references is because you're storing the block for execution later.  I have custom controls that take a block, and I store that block as an iVar.  Those controls are usually retained by the object providing the block, so if the block retains said object, you have a retain cycle...also, if any variable instantiated inside the block retains said object, you again have a retain cycle so long as that variable exists.  This is why I think assigning a __strong var to a passed in __weak var does nothing, as it does not increase the retain count of the object.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you specify a variable as __weak precisely so that the block won't retain it so that you can avoid a retain cycle.  However, creating a __strong Variable inside the block and pointing it to the __weak variable is completely superfluous.  You designate it as weak so that the block won't retain it.  Creating a new one and designating it as __strong doesn't mean anything because there's no instance whereby the block will need to retain it. __strong is only a compiler keyword to tell ARC to retain the value if the need arrives...and ARC will never find that need since it's already been passed into the block.  In the end, you could simply use the weakRequest variable and do away with the strongRequest variable.

Answer (score 2):

You may be confused because there are two different things going on, to prevent two different problems.  You quoted this line:

```
__strong ASIHTTPRequest *strongRequest = weakRequest;
```

That line does **not** prevent a retain cycle.

The (potential) retain cycle is one problem.  The retain cycle would contain three objects: `self`, the `ASIHTTPRequest`, and the block.  Use of the `weakRequest` variable breaks that cycle, because the block captures the `weakRequest`, which does not own the `ASIHTTPRequest` object.  In reference count terms, assigning te `weakRequest` does not increment the reference count of the `ASIHTTPRequest`.

The line you quoted is there to prevent the *other* problem, which is created by solving the first problem.  The other problem is a potential dangling pointer.  Since `weakRequest` doesn't own the `ASIHTTPRequest`, there's a risk that during the execution of the completion block, all owners of the `ASIHTTPRequest` will release it.  Then `weakRequest` will be a dangling pointer - a pointer to an object that has been deallocated.  Any use of it is likely to cause a crash or heap corruption.

In the line you quoted, the block copies `weakRequest` to `strongRequest`.  Because `strongRequest` is `__strong`, the compiler generates code to retain (increment the reference count of) the `ASIHTTPRequest`, and code to release it at the end of the block.  This means that even if all other owners of the `ASIHTTPRequest` release it while the block is running, the `ASIHTTPRequest` will stay alive because the block has temporarily made itself an owner of the request.

Note that this solution to the dangling pointer problem is not thread-safe.  If the owners of the request can release it from other threads while block is executing, there is a race condition that can still lead to a dangling pointer.  This is why you should try to use `__weak` instead of `__unsafe_unretained` for weak pointers: `__weak` references can be copied to `__strong` references without a race condition.

Comment: I don't believe the __weak request variable will be a dangling pointer if the object it refers to is destroyed.  Instead, it will point to nil.  It would only dangle if you use __unsafe_unretained.

Comment: If you look at the code in the question, you will see that it uses `__unsafe_unretained`, not `__weak` (even though the variable is named `weakRequest`).

Comment: Also, the copy to a strong reference is necessary even if you use `__weak` instead of `__unsafe_unretained`, because otherwise the `__weak` reference can become `nil` at any time.  Using `__weak` instead of `__unsafe_unretained` simply prevents use of a zombie reference and prevents the race condition.

Comment: Oh, I see that you're right about __unsafe_retained, I missed that in the question.  But I'm not certain about needing to use __strong inside the block, or even that it's desirable.  Presumably, if all other references to the object are gone except the one the block has, what point is there in accessing that object if the block is just going to go away and the object along with it?

Comment: Also, if using __strong inside the block causes ARC to retain the object, then by definition, you have the possibility of a retain cycle if the retain is on the object referencing the block (directly or indirectly).  This then would negate the reason to use __weak on the variable passed to the block in the first place.

Comment: A temporary retain cycle is fine.  You just have to make sure the retain cycle will be broken by the time all of the objects in the cycle should be deallocated.  In the example code, the compiler generates a release of `strongRequest` at the end of the block, which breaks the retain cycle that the assignment to `strongRequest` created.

Comment: hi rob you are saying its thread safe but here is an article that author says that its not in the last paragraph. please check http://blog.random-ideas.net/?p=160#comment-1158

Comment: in his last paragraph he says the last pattern addresses all thread safety issues shown in that [article.](http://blog.random-ideas.net/?p=160) so i think by that last thread safety concern he mean that its not completely thread safe, we still need to consider synchronization issues required for a code to be completely thread safety. but its thread safe when capturing self in blocks. am i right?